# Razor Checkbox calling ControllerAction in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have a Database that contains several Booleans. I'm displaying this database in my View but I want the user to be able to change the value behind the checkbox.

Is it possible to define some kind of onChange or onClick event for Html Checkboxes in Razor? Kind of like an Action link, so I can call the corresponding Controller Action to change the value?

Preferably without having to use too much JS or AJAX

Comment: JavaScript and AJAX is precisely what you would use.  You'd attach a JavaScript event handler to your `<input>` elements (probably the `change` event) and make an AJAX call to a server-side action to perform your server-side logic.

Comment: Why don't you want to use JavaScript or AJAX? You should learn to use the right tools for the job.